# The exponencial/power with decimals in Solidity

Tags: solidity

I want to make this exponencial operation in solidity:

```
3^0.1 = 1.11
```

I know that in Solidity is not posible to use decimal values so how can I workaround this operation?

I tried to make this possible with WEI but I can't because of the result is too big.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the ABDKMath library, or you can just multiply to a higher exponent to represent the floating point (eg: 10000 could represent 100%)

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "https://github.com/abdk-consulting/abdk-libraries-solidity/blob/master/ABDKMath64x64.sol";

contract Test {
    function power() public pure returns (uint) {
        // Represent 3 as a fixed-point number.
        int128 three = ABDKMath64x64.fromUInt(3);

        // Calculate ln(3)
        int128 lnThree = ABDKMath64x64.ln(three);

        // Represent 0.1 as a fixed-point number.
        int128 oneTenth = ABDKMath64x64.divu(1, 10);

        // Calculate 0.1 * ln(3)
        int128 product = ABDKMath64x64.mul(lnThree, oneTenth);

        // Calculate e^(0.1*ln(3))
        int128 result = ABDKMath64x64.exp(product);

        // Multiply by 10^5 to keep 5 decimal places
        result = ABDKMath64x64.mul(result, ABDKMath64x64.fromUInt(10**5));

        // Convert the fixed-point result to a uint and return it.
        return ABDKMath64x64.toUInt(result);
    }
}
```

heres a link to their readme:
https://github.com/abdk-consulting/abdk-libraries-solidity/blob/master/ABDKMath64x64.md